# ASCII art minesweeper clone

Tags: python, game, python-2.x, ascii-art, minesweeper

I wanted to code a small ASCII art minesweeper clone, to see what it looked like and how much code it needed.

The result is not so bad, under 80 new lines of code in total. It looks kinda readable to me, but I wrote it just know, so I'm biased.

**Input checking...**

I feel like I got pretty much obsessed with input checking, so much that entering garbage will always produce nice error reports to the user and not crash.

**Parsing coordinates is a worthy effort**

Validating and parsing coordinates of the form `LETTER + NUMBER` is a pain, but I feel like that input format is user friendly, so it is going to remain that way.

**Separation of concerns**

The interaction with the outside world is all inside the main `minesweeper` function, because mixing concerns of logic and interaction together makes the code unreadable.

**Doctests**

The code has some doctests, as I feel like seeing an example usage of a function makes the code easier to read (apart from giving a sanity check).

**Re-use**

I re-used some of my old code, a module about the game of life and a module about the user interaction for this. You can find them in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/CAridorc/a26f8f44ed0248d46044).

```
import doctest
import string
import random

import life
from user_interface import general_input

MINE = -1

def minesweeper():
    size = general_input("The size of the board? ", type_=int, set_=range(1, 9+1))
    mines = general_input("The number of mines? ", type_=int, set_=range(1, size*size+1))
    board = random_mineswepper_board(size, mines)

    already_seen = set()
    while True:
        print(''.join(show_board(board, already_seen)))
        raw_coordinates = general_input(
            "Enter the coordinates: ",
            costum_validation = lambda coord: is_coordinate_input_valid(coord, board),
            costum_validation_error = """
Coordinate must be in the form LETTER + NUMBER
And must not exceed the size of the board.
    Example: B4
"""
            )
        x, y = parse_coordinates(raw_coordinates)

        already_seen.add((x,y))
        if is_mine(x, y, board):
            print("You hit a mine!\nGame Over|")
            print(''.join(show_board(board, already_seen)))
            break

def is_coordinate_input_valid(coords, board):
    """
    >>> is_coordinate_input_valid('FoooBar', random_mineswepper_board(3, 1))
    False
    >>> is_coordinate_input_valid('C2', random_mineswepper_board(5, 2))
    True
    >>> is_coordinate_input_valid('Z4', random_mineswepper_board(3, 2)) # Out of bounds
    False
    """
    return len(coords) == 2 and \
           coords[0].lower() in string.ascii_lowercase and \
           coords[1] in string.digits and \
           string.ascii_lowercase.index(coords[0].lower()) < len(board) and \
           int(coords[1]) <= len(board)

def random_mineswepper_board(size, number_of_mines):
    """
    >>> random.seed(0)
    >>> random_mineswepper_board(3, 2)
    [[1, 1, 0], [-1, 2, 1], [1, 2, -1]]
    """
    board = [ [0 for _  in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]
    mined = set()
    for _ in range(number_of_mines):
        x, y = random.randint(0, len(board) - 1), random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)
        while (x, y) in mined:
            x, y = random.randint(0, len(board) - 1), random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)
        board[x][y] = MINE
        mined.add((x,y))
    return list(life.in_chunks_of(size,
               [MINE if cell == MINE else nears.count(MINE)
                   for cell, nears in life.with_neightbors(board)]))

def show_board(board, already_seen, sep = ' | ', cheat=False):
    """
    >>> print(''.join(show_board([[2,2,1],[-1,-1,1],[2,2,1]], {}, cheat=True)))
      | A | B | C | 
    1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 
    2 | M | M | 1 | 
    3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 
    <BLANKLINE>

    """
    print(' ' + sep + sep.join(string.ascii_uppercase[i] for i in range(0, len(board))) + sep)
    for x, _ in enumerate(board):
        yield str(x + 1) + sep
        for y, _ in enumerate(board[0]):
            if True if cheat else (x, y) in already_seen:
                yield 'M' if board[x][y] == MINE else str(board[x][y])
            else:
                yield 'X'
            yield sep
        yield '\n'

def parse_coordinates(coords):
    """
    >>> parse_coordinates('C2')
    (1, 2)
    """
    return (int(coords[1]) - 1, string.ascii_lowercase.index(coords[0].lower()))

def is_mine(x, y, board):
    """
    >>> is_mine(0, 0, [[MINE]])
    True
    """
    return board[x][y] == MINE

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
    random.seed()
    minesweeper()
```

Comment: How does the actual ascii-art output look?

Comment: @SimonForsberg well, it is just a grid, not really "art" -> https://gist.github.com/CAridorc/e6e72dd4067f84e2f79b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does look kind readable, but there are points I would like to address, in addition to most of the points by codesparkle.

- *Please do use `print` function* - Even though Python 2.7, I think it's better to use the print function to ease the bridge within Python 3 and Python 2. You could however use the future import
- *What is `general_input()`?* – This sounds like an interesting function, which would be nice to see (and required to get your code to work). (*Added: The `general_input` is found [here](https://gist.github.com/CAridorc/a26f8f44ed0248d46044#file-user_interface-py), and does provide some interesting reading.*)
- *Complete `show_board()`* – It's kind of strange to see the `print( ''.join(...))` construct calling `show_board()`. I think you should move the `join()` within the function, which would remove the clutter from your main code. (See last point of mine)
- *Strange formatting when inputting coordinates* – This is a minor detail, but I get confused when reading the code where you input coordinates. The kind of loose "Enter the coordinates" I see the reasoning behind, but the following lines with long lines and breaking of indentation makes it a little hard to read. Here are some ideas to clean it up:

  - Possibly use `\` to allow for breaking the line and start the new line with the parameter value
  - Either have the custom validation error as a constant at top of file, or use something like [textwrap.dedent](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to keep the text indented in your code (but still nicely output).

  Here is one variant use `textwrap.dedent`:

  ```
  raw_coordinates = general_input(
      "Enter the coordinates: ",
      custom_validation = \
          lambda coord: is_coordinate_input_valid(coord, board),
      custom_validation_error = textwrap.dedent(
          """Coordinate must be in the form LETTER + NUMBER
          And must not exceed the size of the board.
              Example: B4
          """
      )
  ```

  Using the dedent function has the added benefit of making the ending parentheses, `)`, pop out a little more and thusly helping to clarify the code block. I would also consider changing the `costum_validation` to either `custom_validation` or even simpler `validation`. No need to specify that it is custom, as if it is present you already know it is specific...
- *Join `is_coordinates_valid_input` and `parse_coordinates`* – To have a parse coordinates that doesn't validate it's input is kind of strange, and at the same time to duplicate the logic is bad. My suggestions is therefore to convert the coordinates within `parse_coordinates` and simplify the `is_coordinates_valid_input` into something like the following (using size of the board, and not the board itself):

  ```
  import string
  import doctest

  def is_coordinates(coords, board_size):
      """Verifies that the coords is actual coordinates within the board.

      >>> is_coordinates('C4', 5)
      True

      >>> is_coordinates('Z99', 100)
      True

      >>> is_coordinates('Hi there', 'Bye')
      False

      >>> is_coordinates('Z99', 5)
      False
      """    
      try:
          row, col = parse_coordinates(coords, board_size)
          return True

      except ValueError:
          return False

  def parse_coordinates(coords, board_size):
      """Converts text to coordinate pair, and verifies legality.

      >>> parse_coordinates('C4', 5)
      (3, 2)

      >>> parse_coordinates('Z99', 100)
      (98, 25)

      >>> parse_coordinates('Hi there', 'Bye')
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      ValueError: Coordinates needs to be in the form LETTER + NUMBER, i.e. 'C4'.

      >>> parse_coordinates('Z99', 5)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      ValueError: Coordinates are outside of board.
      """   
      try:
          col = string.ascii_lowercase.index(coords[0].lower())
          row = int(coords[1:]) - 1


      except (IndexError, ValueError):
          raise ValueError("Coordinates needs to be in the form LETTER + NUMBER, i.e. 'C4'.")

      if not ( 0 < row < board_size and 0 < col < board_size):
              raise ValueError("Coordinates are outside of board.")

      return row, col
  ```

  The actual code is short, but the doctests are longer... However this code only use relies on one convertion, not two like in your code. And you get the added benefit of actually verifying the coordinates when parsing them.
- ***Bug/feature:** It is not possible to win?!* – In your game you can only loose by hitting a mine. You can't not win and exit the game...
- ***Feature missing:** I would love for a method to place a flag* – I miss the opportunity to actually place a flag on where I believe a mine exists. In your code I have to remember all the mines I've found
- *Use `random.randrange(size)` instead of `random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)`* - The former should return the same range of random numbers, but it reads easier and shortens the code. Or even `size - 1` is better than needlessly calculating the `len(board)` multiple times.
- ***Feature?** Doctest on random creation of board?!* – If this test actually works, doesn't that mean your random creation is not very random? Does your call to `random.seed()` after the `doctest.testmod()` salvage this one?
- *Use list comprehension and a inner function on `show_board()`* - In addition to points made my codesparkle, related to use of `for` loops and `enumerate` I would consider changing this into list comprehensions directly, and/or possibly use an inner function so that you could make the `show_board()` actually output the board as the function name indicates. This last part can be done like the following:

  ```
  def show_board(board, already_seen, sep = ' | ', cheat=False):
      """
      >>> show_board([[2,2,1],[-1,-1,1],[2,2,1]], {}, cheat=True)
        | A | B | C | 
      1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 
      2 | M | M | 1 | 
      3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 
      <BLANKLINE>

      """
      def _show_board():
          print(' ' + sep + sep.join(string.ascii_uppercase[i] for i in range(0, len(board))) + sep)
          for x, _ in enumerate(board):
              yield str(x + 1) + sep
              for y, _ in enumerate(board[0]):
                  if True if cheat else (x, y) in already_seen:
                      yield 'M' if board[x][y] == MINE else str(board[x][y])
                  else:
                      yield 'X'
                  yield sep
              yield '\n'

      print(''.join(_show_board()))
  ```

  Notice how the inner function uses the same scope as the outer function, so you don't need to pass all parameters. And this is actually considered good style, and not counted as using globals. Using this you can now call `show_board(...)` in your main code, and it automatically does the join and print by it self.

  By the way, there is a **feature** that fails the doctest as you hard code `'M'` within `show_board()` when `cheat = True`. Go with the other suggestion of using `MINE = '*'` and use that as the yielded value.

On a final note, I think you've done quite a lot of nice stuff here, but there are room for improvements and clarifications as suggested above. I haven't gotten around to implementing your special interfaces, and as such I haven't actually managed to test all of it. So code presented is untested, but you should get the gist of it.

Comment: Take your time :) By the way I like this review, in-depth as always.

Answer (score 9):

Overall, your code is quite good. But there's always room for improvement:

## Syntax & Spelling

- Your question is tagged as [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) so use [`print` as a statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) rather than as a function, or, *better yet*, use `from __future__ import print_function` to gain access to this feature.
- Indexing with magic numbers, such as `coords[1]`, is ugly. Prefer sequence unpacking: `col, row = coords`
- Overuse of the ternary operator:

  ```
  if True if cheat else (x, y) in already_seen:
  ```

  This is probably the most confusing line of Python code I have ever come across.
  Equivalent to:

  ```
  if cheat or (x, y) in already_seen:
  ```

  Which would you rather read when trying to comprehend someone else's code?
- Use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of `range` unless you need to keep the list
- c**u**st**o**m, not c**o**st**u**m
- neighbors, not neigh**t**bors

## Structure & Logic

- Overall, this seems well structured, with sensible use of functions.
  However, `is_mine` is only used once and should probably be inlined—here, the function does not provide a higher level of abstraction than just writing out the code: `board[x][y] == MINE`
- Your coordinate validation can be simplified. Instead of scanning through all these lists, use the convenience methods defined in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

  ```
  try:
      col, row = coords
      return (col.isalpha() and
              row.isdigit() and
              col.upper() < string.ascii_uppercase[board_size] and
              int(row) <= board_size)
  except ValueError:
      return False
  ```

  Notice that I replaced `board` with `board_size` in `is_coordinate_input_valid`. There's no need to pass in the whole board when all we need is its size.
- `show_board` does not actually print the board, so it should be renamed to something like `format_board`. In it, you do this twice:

  ```
  for x, _ in enumerate(board):
  ```

  Why bother using `enumerate` when you through away the second element of the result? Just use

  ```
  for x in xrange(len(board)):
  ```
- If `MINE = 'M'` instead of `MINE = -1`, then you could avoid another ternary expression when printing the board: `yield str(board[x][y])`
- There's no need to call `random.seed` at the bottom.

Apart from these (mostly minor) issues, the code is easy to follow. Kudos for using doctests!

Comment: *"use print as a statement rather than as a function"* - I don't hear people suggest this often. People usually say the opposite because of compatability with Python 3, so what's the reason for your suggestion?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I, too, prefer the print function. The original code pretends to use print as a function, masking the fact that it is a statement in Python 2.x — later on, someone might try to pass an additional argument (such as `sep`) and fail. The best choice would indeed be to import the print function from `__future__`. Failing that, at least the statement should be used properly. I am editing my answer to communicate this better.